# Font Awesome possui CSS Reset?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Quando se utiliza o Bootstrap por exemplo, ele tem um CSS Reset interno. A mesma coisa acontece quando se utiliza Font Awesome?

Caso utilize Font Awesome em um projeto, será necessário adicionar algum CSS Reset ou a mesma já vem com um interno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*CSS Reset* não é uma preocupação do *FontAwesome*. Não é necessário incluir nenhum tipo de Reset para seu uso.

Por consequência, seu código não inclui nenhum tipo de ajuste padrão de propriedades globais, como pode ser visto no [repositório do projeto](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/41b9ed01103e6820c3cb043ba7ddab30ecd3f4c0/css/font-awesome.css).

Comment: No meu caso o projeto deverá ter um CSS Reset. Devo então  providenciar fora à parte, pois a Font Awesome não utiliza.

Comment: @anderson Sim, eu diria que este é o caso. Dependendo do seu projeto, um dos resets disponíveis em http://cssreset.com/ pode atender às suas necessidades.